# server not respond to browser but ok with ssh or ping

Tags: ssh, web-server, apache-2.4

Server has been up and running for 20 days. but since 10:00am this morning its cannot be queried via browser. SSH and ping both ok.

In browser I also tried to type IP address directly instead of domain name but still got an error:

```
This webpage is not available
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

No interesting messages in apache logs or ssh logs. After reboot website is recovered. Can anybody tell me how to figure out the root reason for this failure, please?

Comment: Maybe, your apache server has stopped and the reboot fixed this by starting apache during system startup.

Comment: configure proper monitoring